# BLE thermal printer font configuration on iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, thermal-printer

I faced this issue working with CoreBluetooth on iOS trying to connect to a thermal printer(munByn) and printing a certain text using a specific font size. 
This issue was problematic since both Android and iOS were printing to the same printer. The android app was sending a certain configuration to set the font size which changed the whole format of my printed text. 
The solution i had to adopt was setting the configuration my self before printing by sending data (exact bytes) to set the font size as desired. 
What is the exact byte array i should send?

Answer (score 1):

I found an example inside a library called printer-master in a class called command.swift here https://github.com/KevinGong2013/Printer. 
I solved the issue as follows:

```
var dataArr : [Data] = []
dataArr.append(Data(bytes: [27, 33, n ])) // where n can be set to be a number between 0 and 99 i guess
dataArr.append("text to be printed\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

for data in dataArr {
  printer.writeValue(data, for: characteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)
}
```

note that data shouldn't be bigger than 182 i think (or a very close number).
Hope this helps you out.